# add details to to HTTP response when eceiving HTTP requst

Tags: http, validation, azure-logic-apps, http-status-code-400, custom-error-handling

I have created a logic app to receive an http request and validate the content which is fine. But when I receive the 400 error message, it said only that it was expecting an integer but received a string for example. I would like to add the name of the field that generates the error is it possible?

**postman response**
[image]

I added an http response to be executed when the requst fails but it's never triggered.

**logic flow**

[image]

Comment: Without API URL's parameters, how to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign http response to a variable and then you can check which filed is causing error.
I have reproduced issue from my side and below are steps I followed,

1. Initially created logic app as shown below,
   [image]
2. Payload of http trigger is,
   [image]
   Logic app trigger is enabled with schema validation,
   [image]
3. I have tried to run trigger with below payload,

```
{
    "number":1600,
    "street_name":"pennsylvania",
    "street_type":7
}
```

Got error **"*Failed to start a run of logic app alertschlapp. The input body for trigger 'manual' of type 'Request' did not match its schema definition. Error details: 'Invalid type. Expected String but got Integer.'.*"**
[image]

4. Next modified logic app as shown below,
   [image]
5. Added three initialize variables action for number, street_name and street_type
   number:
   [image]
   street_name:
   [image]
   street_type:
   [image]
6. Ran the logic app with below payload,

```
"number":1600,
    "street_name":"pennsylvania",
    "street_type":7
```

7. Logic app failed with below error,
   [image]
   In this way, you can find out which field value is causing issue.

Comment: You need to extend your answer to return the error to the calling application. That’s what the OP is wanting.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, now if I want to send the name of that variable in http response in case it fails. is ther a way to capture that ?

Comment: yes, you can send name of the variable in response by configuring run after option and sending variable name in response body.

Comment: when i send good payload i recive a 503 error and it seems that the response action generate this message if there is no error in the flow. is there a way to change this into 200 code.

Comment: @Skin you are absolutly wright i still can't capture the error message from the varibales. if I activate the scehma validation at the reception the reste of the actions are not activated. and if remove the validation thevariable that has error is flagged but the response can't catch the varibale name: (InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Response' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'Template language expression cannot be evaluated: the template variable 'number' cannot be found.'.)

Comment: Use a scope action to solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you @Skin. it's new for me i'm going to test that.

Comment: You will need to turn off the schema validation on the trigger though, otherwise you won’t be able to catch anything.